# Deploying existing web application under Ofbiz

Tags: java, ofbiz

Ofbiz newbie here.

**What is the best way to deploy an existing spring-mvc based web application (runs under tomcat) under Ofbiz?**

What I have tried so far (without luck) -

- Create *hotdeploy/myapp/ofbiz-component.xml*
- Expand the .war file into *hotdeploy/myapp/webapp/myapp* (such that web-inf is under hotdeploy/myapp/webapp/myapp)

*ofbiz-component.xml*  contents -

```
<ofbiz-component name="cms"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ofbiz.apache.org/dtds/ofbiz-component.xsd";>

<resource-loader name="main" type="component" />
<webapp name="myapp"
        title="myapp"
        server="default-server"
        location="webapp/myapp"
        mount-point="/myapp"/>

</ofbiz-component>
```

I also tried create-component route as described [here](http://www.hotwaxmedia.com/ofbiz-tutorial-custom-components-in-ofbiz/#.Un6l5vmkriY) (based on some other SO answer) but that introduced Ofbiz controllers, etc (that i don't yet understand) and prevents the spring-mvc dispatcher servlet from working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

See if there were errors loading this ofbiz-component.xml file. I see a couple of extraneous semicolons (lines 2 and 4 the way it is formatted here). Also the name attribute should be "myapp", but "cms" may be unique and if so should work.

Also make sure it is in "hot-deploy" and not "hotdeploy".

Yes, no point using the create-component ant target, it creates a bunch of stuff you won't want for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the version of ofbiz you are using.

With the latest release they [stopped supporting to deploy as external server](http://ofbiz.135035.n4.nabble.com/Deploy-Ofbiz-with-Tomcat-8-td4715475.html)